# RecyclerView adapter issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

I have an issue while loading data in adapter view of recycle view.

I have two `Fragment` in activity and 2nd `Fragment` have 3 recycle views. But the problem is that I have a `checkbox` in raw view holder, I checked some one of that. when i scroll up /down then that data of `recycleview` data rearrange as default and all check boxes are again false.

I used set recycle(false) in on bind method but still not working.

```
public class VenueOrderPriceAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<VenueOrderPriceAdapter.DataViewHolder> {

    static Context mContext;
    public static double final_total;
    public static String selected_hr,selected_min;

    static private List<VenueOrderPriceModel> stList;
    static private String str_id, str_charges, str_is_flat_charges, str_is_per_person_charges;
            /*str_hour_extension_charges, str_extra_person_charges=null, str_is_group_size, str_group_size_from,
            str_group_size_to*/;
    private static boolean isPkgAdded;

    public VenueOrderPriceAdapter(Context mContext, List<VenueOrderPriceModel> students) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.stList = students;
    }

    // Create new views
    @Override
    public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_venueorder_price, parent,false);
        Log.e("on create called---","dsdf--111");
        // create ViewHolder

        DataViewHolder viewHolder = new DataViewHolder(itemLayoutView);

        final_total=0;


        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DataViewHolder viewHolder, final int positiona) {
        Log.e("on bind called---","dsdf"+positiona);
        viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);


    }

    // Return the size arraylist
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stList.size();
    }

    public static class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvName,tv_details,tv_duration ,tv_guestCount,tv_price,tv_extra_charge,tv_addtocart,tv_pkg_rate;
        CheckBox cb_selectedprice;
        private LinearLayout ll_extra,ll_extra_charge;
        Spinner sp_hh,sp_mm,sp_qty;
        ImageView img_clock,img_guest,img_remove;

        public DataViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);


            tvName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tv_details = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tv_details);
            tv_duration = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tv_duration);
            tv_guestCount = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tv_guestCount);
            tv_price =  (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
            tv_extra_charge =   (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tv_extra_charge);
            tv_pkg_rate  =   (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tv_pkg_rate);

            img_clock  =   (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.img_clock);
            img_guest  =   (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.img_guest);
            img_remove  =   (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.img_remove);

            sp_hh = (Spinner)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sp_hh);
            sp_mm = (Spinner)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sp_mm);
            sp_qty = (Spinner)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sp_qty);

          //  tv_ext_person= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ext_person);

            ll_extra =(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_extra);
            ll_extra_charge  =(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_extra_charge);

            tv_addtocart= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_addtocart);

            cb_selectedprice =(CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_selectedprice);


            final int position = getAdapterPosition();

            String extra_duration_charge = "";
            str_id= stList.get(position).getId();

            if(stList.get(position).getIs_applicable().equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                itemView.setEnabled(false);
                itemView.setClickable(false);
                itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.md_blue_grey_50);
                tv_addtocart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            tvName.setText(stList.get(position).getPackage_name());

            tv_details.setText(stList.get(position).getChrages_inclusion());

            tv_price.setText(" $ "+Const.GLOBAL_FORMATTER.format(Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges())));

            if(stList.get(position).getPacakage_hours()!=null){
                tv_duration.setText(stList.get(position).getPacakage_hours().substring(0,stList.get(position).getPacakage_hours().length()-3)+" hr");
            }else{
                tv_duration.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if(stList.get(position).getIs_group_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                tv_guestCount.setText(stList.get(position).getGroup_size_from()
                        +"-"
                        +stList.get(position).getGroup_size_to() +" Guest");
            }else{
                tv_guestCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }



    //======EXTRA GUEST AND TIME CONDITION FOR TEXT VIEW ==========================================
                if(stList.get(position).getIs_hour_extension_charges()!=null) {
                    if(stList.get(position).getIs_hour_extension_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                        ll_extra_charge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        if (stList.get(position).getExtension_hours().substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase("00")) {
                            extra_duration_charge = "$ " + stList.get(position).getHour_extension_charges() + " / " + stList.get(position).getExtension_hours().substring(3, 5) + " min";
                        } else {
                            extra_duration_charge = "$ " + stList.get(position).getHour_extension_charges() + " / " + stList.get(position).getExtension_hours().substring(0, 5) + " hours";
                        }

                        tv_extra_charge.setText(extra_duration_charge);
                    }
                }


                if(stList.get(position).getIs_group_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1") &&  stList.get(position).getIs_extra_person_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){

                    extra_duration_charge = extra_duration_charge+"\n"+"$"+stList.get(position).getIs_extra_person_charges()+"/ person";
                    tv_extra_charge.setText(extra_duration_charge);
                }
                if(extra_duration_charge==null || extra_duration_charge.length()<1){
                    ll_extra_charge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if(stList.get(position).getIs_flat_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                        tv_pkg_rate.setText("Flat Rate");
                    } else if(stList.get(position).getIs_perperson_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                        tv_pkg_rate.setText("Per Person");
                    } else if(stList.get(position).getIs_perhour_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        tv_pkg_rate.setText("Per Hour");
                    }
                }else{
                    if(stList.get(position).getIs_flat_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                        tv_pkg_rate.setText("Flat Rate");
                    } else if(stList.get(position).getIs_perperson_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                        tv_pkg_rate.setText("Per Person");
                    } else if(stList.get(position).getIs_perhour_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        tv_pkg_rate.setText("Per Hour");
                    }
                }


    //==========FLAT PER PERSON PER HOURE CHARGES CONDITION======================================================
                if(stList.get(position).getIs_flat_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                    ll_extra.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    // tv_ext_person.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                } else if(stList.get(position).getIs_perperson_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){

                    if(stList.get(position).getIs_group_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1") &&  stList.get(position).getExtra_person_charges()!=null){
                        ll_extra.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        img_clock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        sp_hh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //np_itemcount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        // tv_ext_person.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //np_itemcount.setMaxValue(Integer.parseInt(stList.get(position).getGroup_size_to()));
                    }else{
                        ll_extra.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //tv_ext_person.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }

                    if(stList.get(position).getIs_extra_person_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                        ll_extra.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //tv_ext_person.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }else if(stList.get(position).getIs_perhour_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    ll_extra.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    img_guest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    sp_qty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //ll_duration.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


                List<String> list_hh = new ArrayList<String>();
                list_hh.add("HH");
                list_hh.add("01");
                list_hh.add("02");
                list_hh.add("03");
                list_hh.add("04");
                list_hh.add("05");
                list_hh.add("06");
                list_hh.add("07");
                list_hh.add("08");
                list_hh.add("09");
                list_hh.add("10");
                list_hh.add("11");
                list_hh.add("12");

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter_hh = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list_hh);
                dataAdapter_hh.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sp_hh.setAdapter(dataAdapter_hh);


                List<String> list_mm = new ArrayList<String>();
                list_mm.add("MM");
                list_mm.add("00");
                list_mm.add("15");
                list_mm.add("30");
                list_mm.add("45");

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter_mm = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list_mm);
                dataAdapter_mm.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sp_mm.setAdapter(dataAdapter_mm);

                List<String> list_qty = new ArrayList<String>();
                list_qty.add("Guest");
                for(int a=0;a<100;a++){
                    list_qty.add(Integer.toString(a));
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter_qty = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list_qty);
                dataAdapter_qty.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sp_qty.setAdapter(dataAdapter_qty);


                sp_hh.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int positionSP, long id) {

                        if(sp_mm.getSelectedItemPosition()>1 && positionSP>1){
                            final_total = Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges())+(Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges()) * (double) (sp_hh.getSelectedItemPosition()  +1) );
                        }else{
                            if(positionSP > 1) {
                                final_total = Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges())+(Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges()) * (double) (sp_hh.getSelectedItemPosition()));
                            }else{
                                final_total = Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges());
                            }
                        }
                    /* Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Time : " +
                                         sp_hh.getItemAtPosition(sp_hh.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString()
                                        + ":"
                                        +String.valueOf(sp_mm.getSelectedItem()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });



                sp_mm.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int positionSP, long id) {
                        if(positionSP>1){
                            final_total = Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges())+(Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges()) *(double) (sp_hh.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1 ));
                            // tv_menutitle_venuepricing.setText("Pricing Plans "+" ( Total : "+final_total+" )");
                        }else{
                            if(sp_hh.getSelectedItemPosition()>0){
                                final_total =Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges())+(Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges()) * (double) (sp_hh.getSelectedItemPosition()));
                            }else{
                                final_total = Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges());
                            }
                        }
                                /*Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Time : " + sp_hh.getItemAtPosition(sp_hh.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString()
                                        + ":" +sp_mm.getItemAtPosition(sp_mm.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });



            /*chkSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                    if(chkSelected.isChecked()==true){
                        checked_count=checked_count+1;
                            if(checked_count > 1){
                                chkSelected.setChecked(false);
                                checked_count=checked_count-1;
                                Log.d("chk count ",""+checked_count);
                            }else {
                               Log.d("chk count",""+checked_count);
                                    if(stList.get(position).getIs_perperson_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                                        final_total = Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges()) * Double.parseDouble(et_guestCount.getText().toString());
                                      //  tv_menutitle_venuepricing.setText("Pricing Plans "+" ( Total : "+final_total+" )");

                                    }else if(stList.get(position).getIs_perhour_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                                            if(np_minutes_venue_pkg.getValue()>0){
                                                final_total = Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges()) * (double)(np_hour_venue_pkg.getValue()+1);
                                             //   tv_menutitle_venuepricing.setText("Pricing Plans "+" ( Total : "+final_total+" )");
                                            }else{
                                                if(np_hour_venue_pkg.getValue()>0) {
                                                    final_total = Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges()) * (double) (np_hour_venue_pkg.getValue());
                                                  //  tv_menutitle_venuepricing.setText("Pricing Plans " + " ( Total : "+ Const.GLOBAL_FORMATTER.format(final_total) + " )");
                                                }else{
                                                    final_total = Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges());
                                                    //tv_menutitle_venuepricing.setText("Pricing Plans " + " ( Total : "+ Const.GLOBAL_FORMATTER.format(final_total) + " )");
                                                }
                                            }

                                            selected_hr= Integer.toString(np_hour_venue_pkg.getValue());
                                            if(selected_hr.length()<=1){
                                                selected_hr="0"+selected_hr;
                                            }

                                            selected_min=Integer.toString(np_minutes_venue_pkg.getValue());
                                            if(selected_min.length()<=1){
                                                selected_min="0"+selected_min;
                                            }

                                    }else if(stList.get(position).getIs_flat_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){

                                        if(stList.get(position).getIs_group_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1") && stList.get(position).getIs_extra_person_charges().equalsIgnoreCase("1") ){
                                            int guest_from =Integer.parseInt(stList.get(position).getGroup_size_from());
                                            int guest_to =Integer.parseInt(stList.get(position).getGroup_size_to());
                                            int guest =Integer.parseInt(et_guestCount.getText().toString());

                                            if(guest>guest_to){
                                                int extra_guest = guest-guest_to;
                                                final_total = ((double)extra_guest * Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getExtra_person_charges()) )
                                                        +Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges());
                                               // tv_menutitle_venuepricing.setText("Pricing Plans " + " ( Total : " + Const.GLOBAL_FORMATTER.format(final_total) + " )");
                                            }else{
                                                final_total = Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges());
                                               // tv_menutitle_venuepricing.setText("Pricing Plans " + " ( Total : "+ Const.GLOBAL_FORMATTER.format(final_total) + " )");
                                            }

                                        }else {
                                            final_total = Double.parseDouble(stList.get(position).getCharges());
                                           // tv_menutitle_venuepricing.setText("Pricing Plans " + " ( Total : "+ Const.GLOBAL_FORMATTER.format(final_total) + " )");
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                    }else{
                        checked_count=checked_count-1;
                        Log.d("chk count",""+checked_count);
                        if(checked_count==0){
                       // tv_menutitle_venuepricing.setText("Pricing Plans ");
                        }
                    }

                    VenueOrderPriceModel contact = (VenueOrderPriceModel) chkSelected.getTag();

                    contact.setSelected(chkSelected.isChecked());
                    stList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(chkSelected.isChecked());
                    *//*Toast.makeText(
                                chkSelected.getContext(),
                                "Clicked on Checkbox: " + chkSelected.getText() + " is "
                                        + chkSelected.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*//*
                }
            });*/




                if (cb_selectedprice.isChecked()==true){
                    img_remove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    img_remove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                img_remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        isPkgAdded=false;
                        cb_selectedprice.setChecked(false);
                        img_remove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        tv_addtocart.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner_orange_white_borde,mContext.getTheme()));
                        tv_addtocart.setEnabled(true);
                        final_total=0;
                    }
                });

                tv_addtocart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (isPkgAdded == true || cb_selectedprice.isChecked()==true) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "First Remove Added Pacakge", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Log.e("boooking details --",str_dateselected+str_guest_count+str_timeslot);
                            }
                    }
                });

            }

        }

        // method to access in activity after updating selection
        public List<VenueOrderPriceModel> getStudentist() {
            return stList;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post your code which you have tried.

Comment: ... which issue?

Comment: Hello Every one, Thanks for comment and help.

i solved my self .

i modify my MODEL class by placing boolean variable and mange that variable from onbind method and click listener.

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain the state of each checkbox in you data model from onCheckChangeListener of checkbox wrt every positions.

Then you have to set the checkbox state in onBind method of adapter

Answer (score 0):

The recycler view recycles the view in OnBindViewHolder. So when items are scrolled view is recycled again.To solve this.

create a global variable to store the clicked position.

```
private mItemSelected=-1;
```

Then inside viewholder add the clickListener and onClick store the position of the clicked item.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mItemSelected = getAdapterPosition();
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in inside OnBindViewHolder,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if(mItemSelected==position){
        holder.status.setChecked(true)‌;
    }else{
        holder.status.setChecked(false)‌;
    }
}
```